# Indeterminate Progress Bar only shows very briefly at the end of the operation

Tags: android, progress-bar

I want it to show up as soon as I click the login button, but it only shows after the loggin process has finished

What am i doing wrong

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        doLogin();          
        mProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: Does doLogin() is a blocking method (not async)?

Comment: Do you call it in the GUI thread?

Comment: @KirillKulakov The code above is in the main thread

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using another thread to show the Visibility, the runnable might get scheduled any time in the future. That is the reason it is being shown late.

Maybe adding a sleep routine in current thread immediately after runonuithread call might schedule the runnable, but you can never be really sure.

Edit: Or you could create a Handler which shows Progress bar and wait for it to be shown and then continue

Comment: that didn't work. but i solved it now by moving all of the doLogin work into an AsyncTask class

Answer (score 0):

The reason You don't see the loading dialog is that you call a blocking function in your GUI thread/MAIN thread.When you set your dialog to visible you should let the GUI thread to keep running so it can draw the dialog on the screen.Moreover after 5 seconds that the GUI thread is blocked, the user will be presented with FORCE CLOSE/Wait pop up.

It is a bad practice to preform long operation of the gui thread, you MUST only can non blocking function in it.

Here is how you should do it:

```
//make sure mProgress is final
mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
new Thread(){
    public void run(){
         doLogin();
         mProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: there is is alot of interaction with UI elements in doLogin() so i'm getting an error that i cant access them for a different thread

Comment: So, if doLogin should be interacive with the user you should do it as an async task, you can use updateprogress to show the login dialog to the user, google async task